# Safari Extension Development - Auto Reload / Inspect Global Page

Tags: macos, safari, applescript, automator, safari-extension

I'm developing a Safari Plugin.

I'd like to add the following workflow to my task runner (Grunt):

1. Bring up the Extension Builder
2. Uninstall my plugin
   *(Possibly restart Safari)* *
3. Re-Add my plugin
4. Install my plugin
5. Inspect the global page
6. Load a test page in Safari
7. Inspect that page
8. Reload that page

I realize that this should be doable via Apple Script/Automator but wanted to get some input into how or if anyone else has attempted this.

**Please be aware, by default Safari loads injected scripts into iframes as well as top level windows/tabs. Both Firefox and Chrome can do this, but do not by default.**